# Error: "To use the controller, please upgrade to a version of Unity with the GVR native integration"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, daydream

I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started) but instead of the Technical Preview I installed 5.6 beta. I have Pixel XL and so connected my Daydream controller instead of a phone with emulator.

When I get into the Editor and load up the demo scene, and run it, I get this message:

> To use the controller, please upgrade to a version of Unity with the GVR native integration

I am not entirely sure what this means, I've searched around a bit and on these forums, and have found no joy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the latest version of Unity 5.6
2. Download the latest SDK
   https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download#google-vr-sdk-for-unity
3. Import the SDK into Unity, make sure you are set to build to Android, and in Edit>ProjectSettings>Player make sure virtual reality is supported and Daydream is added to the list.

To debug the controller in editor, use the controller emulator:
https://developers.google.com/vr/daydream/controller-emulator

That message is also the default text in the DemoInputManager prefab (it probably should not be) - which may mean you have errors in your scene, causing DemoInputManager to fail to update.  If you have done everything above, you can safely ignore that message.