# Error "To use the controller, please upgrade to a version of Unity with the GVR native integration" in Unity and Google VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm a new Unity user, trying to follow the very basic Google VR tutorial for ioS here:
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-ios

I'm using Unity 2017.1 and have downloaded the Google VR SDK from here:
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download#google-vr-sdk-for-unity

When I open the GVdemo scene and press play, I get the message:

> To use the controller, please upgrade to a version of Unity with the GVR native integration.

I don't see the stereo image and the mouse does not respond with or without the Ctrl key clicked.

I have 'Virtual Reality Supported' checked under player settings, with 'Cardboard' selected.

There are several older threads elsewhere with this error - but none that I can find that present a solution. I'm working on Mac OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "To use the controller, please upgrade to a version of Unity with the GVR native integration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868675/error-to-use-the-controller-please-upgrade-to-a-version-of-unity-with-the-gvr)

Comment: [Other possible duplicates](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+To+use+the+controller%2C+please+upgrade+to+a+version+of+Unity+with+the+GVR+native+integration).